# jQuery to Animate after () & before()

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm using Table Drag n Sort plugin from [Github](https://raw.github.com/dfsq/trSortable/master/jquery.trsortable.js)

& Here is Working [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/uyedak/) for that plugin

This plugin sorts table by detecting mouse cursor position after dragging.

So, If you drag Up => It moves selected tr **before** target div

& If you drag Down => It moves selected tr **after** target div

Plugin looks something like this..

```
// ...... //

    if (mouseY > lastY) {
        $(this).after($tr);
    } else {
        $(this).before($tr);
    }

// ...... //
```

My Question is How Do I assign animation to this after() & before () so that sorting will look smooth. currently it just append div instantly.

Any Help will be appreciated !

Comment: It's not meant to work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `position: absolute` of `<tr>` element, then animate position changes, and finally insert `$tr` to new place in DOM and remove `position: absolute`.

But you need to calculate correct positions.

Easier option is:
animate hiding `$tr`, inserting in DOM and showing him.